# Adjust size and center text vertically in a JQuery button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a button html element on my page and want to use the JQuery button so I do

`$( "#myButton" ).button();`

This works great, but I want to edit the style of the button, namely (as it says in the title) I want to make the button shorter with smaller text and center the text vertically. I've tried

```
#myButton {
    height: 22px;
    font-size: 16px !important;
}
```

And this works in terms of making my button and text the size I want them, but it doesn't center the text vertically in the button. I've tried setting `padding-bottom: 2px;`, I've tried setting `line-height: 22px;`, and I've tried setting `vertical-align: center;`, but none have worked. The button still looks like: [image: button image] Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I suspect we're going to need to see a demo.

Comment: @Dmitriy, I appreciate the input but neither of those use the JQuery button element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `padding: 0;` instead `height: 22px;` and your height will be defined by your font-size attribute.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/dmonti/mz8k7kkw/

Comment: thanks for the example. It works in the JSFiddle but not when I try it in my code :(

Comment: You probably have some CSS affecting your span tag or used class, can you import all yours CSS files into my JSFiddle example?

Comment: Hey, so I just realized that your example lets the button size be determined by the text size. I want to set both. I want text to be 16px and button height to be 22px; If I add to your fiddle's css `height: 22px !important;`, then it replicates my issue.

Comment: Ok, then try to adjust the padding of this CSS selector: `#myButton > span`, you could start with `padding: 0 5px;`

JSFiddle updated: https://jsfiddle.net/dmonti/mz8k7kkw/

Comment: Why do I have to declare the `padding` in there vs in `#myButton`?

Comment: To override this JQuery UI CSS from jquery-ui.css imported file:
`.ui-button-text-only .ui-button-text  {
    padding: .4em 1em;
}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85133/discussion-between-bagelboy-and-daniel-monti).

Answer (score 2):

For centering small elements relative to a parent I usually just use absolute positioning:

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <span>Process</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    position: relative;
    border: 5px solid grey;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
}

span {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    transform: translate(50%, 50%);
}
```

The important things to note here are that your "Process" element is self-contained (inside it's own `span` element), and that its parent element's `position` property is set to relative.

The CSS transform property might look a little confusing, but it essentially keeps the element perfectly centered inside of it's parent, no matter how it's resized.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wLzc4fL7/1/)

In my fiddle, you can see how it centers by adjusting the `div`'s `height` property in the css.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed example Jonathan. It sparks a new question, is it common to declare things as spans in HTML if they are just going to be converted in the js using JQuery UI elements? And if so, is it bad practice to declare a button as a <button> in HTML if I'm going to make it a JQuery UI button in the js? Thanks!

Comment: @bagelboy sorry, answered before the edit. I wouldn't say it's bad practice at all! If it works, it works.